# Where do you leave your bike on cafe stops and water breaks?

Tags: safety, lock, long-distance

Where should I leave my bike on longer rides when stopping at a cafe or going into a store to get water?  Do you carry a lock in your jersey? Leave it outside?  What is a good lock?  What should I do so my bike doesn't get stolen?

Comment: This depends on where you are.  In many parts of the world you can safely leave your bike unlocked.  In other parts of the world it will be stolen as soon as you turn around.  Some places a lightweight cable lock is more than sufficient to discourage potential thieves, while in other places a heavy chain is not sufficient.

Comment: See http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/937/locking-your-bike-in-public-areas

Comment: See http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12428/lock-my-bicycle-on-busy-or-quiet-places

Comment: See http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/techniques-for-safely-leaving-a-bike-for-1-2-minutes-in-a-safe-ish-place?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

There is such a range of answers.

A lock mounted to the bike is going to be more comfortable.

A decent light ulock is going to be 1.5 lbs.

A cable lock is going to be more like 0.5 lbs, but not as strong. 
But, for a quick in and out it that may be the best trade off.

The weight of the bike plus the weight of the lock to protect the bike is typically a wash.

In a group you could have one lock and a cable, or just have one person at a time stay out with the bikes.  Alternately, you could just have the cheapest bike in the group.

Some establishments may let you bring the bike in.

If you can see the door then you can remove a wheel and bring it with you. I will loop my helmet through the rear wheel. Not much but you pick 5 seconds. You can run down someone carrying a bike.

Comment: Generally I won't leave my bike where I can't see it AND get to it quickly. I have seen opportune thefts that consisted of a bike tossed into the back of a truck and a quick drive off.  Grocery stores and the like big enough for carts tend to be big enough to bring a bike with, in a smaller store (gas station convenience) I tend to leave the bike just inside the door where it's out of the way, but inconvenient for someone to grab and take through a door quickly.

Comment: @ChrisinAK I know a guy the had the bike stolen off his car while he was paying for gas

Answer (score 2):

If the area doesn't look very "lively", sometimes I just leave my rig outside a shop. My little trick though is I put my bike into some nasty gear, like either the fastest one or smallest/smallest ring combo, so the chain hangs loose. Or even I tune my front derailleur in a way allowing me to get the chain completely off the front chainring (in a way which requires stronger than normal push on the shifter). So in case of emergency I'd hopefully have a couple seconds more to chase the thief.

Comment: In addition I open the quick-releases. If Mr Thief tries to ride away it will go nasty. :-)

Comment: I like the idea! :) But as Chris in AK pointed out, that still doesn't prevent somebody from tossing the bike into back of a truck.. Not many trucks in place I live, so probably that's different from US :)